# nginx reverse proxy is slow, got 499 when load testing and have high upstream_connect_time

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We are load testing one of our application server using Gatling sending ~150 req/s. When we load test by calling the application server directly, everything works fine but when we are calling through nginx which act as a reverse proxy, there are a lot of timeouts (60s) at Gatling.

Looking at nginx logs we saw cases where upstream_connect_time would be '-'

```
{"log":"\"20/Mar/2019:08:26:16 +0000\" client=172.30.14.21 method=POST request=\"POST /api/shopping/log HTTP/1.1\" request_length=5672 status=499 bytes_sent=0 body_byt
es_sent=0 referer=- user_agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36\" upstream_addr=172
.30.106.47:80 upstream_status=- request_time=60.000 upstream_response_time=- upstream_connect_time=- upstream_header_time=-\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-03-20T08:
26:16.593007324Z"}
```

or in some cases, upstream_connect_time goes to 31s

```
{"log":"\"20/Mar/2019:08:26:00 +0000\" client=172.30.14.21 method=POST request=\"POST /api/shopping/log HTTP/1.1\" request_length=5672 status=200 bytes_sent=280 body_bytes_sent=12 referer=- user_agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36\" upstream_addr=172.30.106.47:80 upstream_status=200 request_time=31.154 upstream_response_time=31.154 upstream_connect_time=31.080 upstream_header_time=31.154\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-03-20T08:26:00.355564536Z"}
```

So we imagine this could be something related to connections to an upstream server. We've tried enabled keepalive but it doesn't help. When we tried lower the workers_connection to 512, we would get an error saying 'workers_connection are not enough'. Below is our nginx.conf. What could be the problem here?

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1000;
  use epoll;
  multi_accept on;
}

http {
  log_format main '"$time_local" client=$remote_addr '
               'method=$request_method request="$request" '
               'request_length=$request_length '
               'status=$status bytes_sent=$bytes_sent '
               'body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent '
               'referer=$http_referer '
               'user_agent="$http_user_agent" '
               'upstream_addr=$upstream_addr '
               'upstream_status=$upstream_status '
               'request_time=$request_time '
               'upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time '
               'upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time '
               'upstream_header_time=$upstream_header_time';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
  open_file_cache_valid 30s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
  open_file_cache_errors on;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length 10240;
  gzip_comp_level 1;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_disable msie6;
  gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types
      text/css
      text/javascript
      text/xml
      text/plain
      text/x-component
      application/javascript
      application/x-javascript
      application/json
      application/xml
      application/rss+xml
      application/atom+xml
      font/truetype
      font/opentype
      application/vnd.ms-fontobject
      image/svg+xml;

  reset_timedout_connection on;
  client_body_timeout 10;
  send_timeout 2;
  keepalive_requests 100000;

  upstream backend {
      server 172.30.106.47:80;
      keepalive 128;
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      location = /health {
          return 200;
      }
      location /status {
          stub_status on;
      }
      location / {
          proxy_buffers 32 4m;
          proxy_busy_buffers_size 25m;
          proxy_buffer_size 512k;
          proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          client_max_body_size 1024m;
          client_body_buffer_size 4m;
          proxy_connect_timeout 300;
          proxy_read_timeout 300;
          proxy_send_timeout 300;
          proxy_intercept_errors off;
          stub_status on;
          proxy_pass http://backend;
      }
      location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      }
      error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  }

}
```

Comment: Under load can you connect quickly directly to the server, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Your `send_timeout` is very short. I would start by increasing both timeouts you have as a start.